# PHP - MYSQL: Last 12 months first to last day of each month

Tags: php, mysql

A project I am on has the need to get an average invoice total for each of the the last 12 months. I can easily get what I need by doing 12 queries (1 for each month), but its very ugly, I end up with 12 unique variables(id rather have a loop ), and I know there is a better way.

Can anyone help with the best way to get the following:

```
SELECT AVG(invoice_total) FROM invoice WHERE date between '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-31'
SELECT AVG(invoice_total) FROM invoice WHERE date between '2015-02-01' AND '2015-02-28'
SELECT AVG(invoice_total) FROM invoice WHERE date between '2015-03-01' AND '2015-03-31'
```

etc...

Im plotting these on a graph, so I need a data point for each month.

End result would be something like:

```
Jan: $2323
Feb: $3523
March: $6453
```

ect... but would start 12 months ago from the current month.

Thank you.

P.S. For refrence, this is how I am plotting the last 90 days:

```
$get_unconfirmed_appointments = "
SELECT total
     , invoice_date 
  FROM invoice 
 WHERE clinic_id = 20
   AND invoice_date >= '$date' 
   AND invoice_date <= '$date_two' 
 ORDER 
    BY invoice_date ASC
";
        $result = $conn->query($get_unconfirmed_appointments) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);    
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $totals[$row['invoice_date']][] = $row['total'];
            }
    $sub_arrays = array_chunk($totals, 3);
    foreach ($sub_arrays as $threedays) {
        foreach ($threedays as $value) {
            foreach ($value as $val) {
                $all[] = $val;
            }                                   
        }
        $average = array_sum($all) / count($all);
        $data_point=round($average,2);
        plot($data_point);
    }
```

I need the same idea as above, but for the last 12 months. Average for each month.

Comment: Effort? Sorry, can you elaborate so I dont make mistake again?

Comment: Well, what is '2/29'? What does your data set look like? What have tried? What research have you undertaken?

Comment: I expanded the question. Your first comment on why you down voted is now gone, but the -1 remains?

Comment: My mistake Strawberry, my real code uses variables for the date range. I forgot to include years when I made this question.

Comment: What research have I undertaken? Do you want the question to be 500 lines long?? Ive looked at a bunch of stuff, with no luck, hence why Im asking here. ALSO, I mentioned what I tried.. 12 individual queries. I showed examples of those. My question is: can they be combine into one query like the example I posted after the question.. Everything is there, but this still does not help you?

Comment: While I applicate the help everyone offers, I really don't need to be told that etcetera is abbreviated as etc, not ect.. I don't see how this helps ANYONE answer ANYTHING.

Comment: well the update I made was actually the dates in you sql conditions that weren't clear enough

Comment: 1/1/2015 is the same as 2015/1/1, so I'm not sure how its not clear enough..  Also, how do you know my data is stored in that format? The data in my sql table comes from an outside source that uses format 1/1/2015 (I do reformat to 2015/1/1 before storing tho)

Comment: well some countries use m/d/y format while others use d/m/y, in SQL is more common to write the dates in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MONTHNAME function and group by that:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month
```

You SQL will be something like that:

```
SELECT AVG(invoice_total), MONTHNAME(invoice_date)  FROM invoice WHERE invoice_date BETWEEN '2014-11-11'  AND '2015-02-09' GROUP BY MONTHNAME(invoice_date)
```